# Скрипт выполняется, но ничего не происходит

Tags: ajax, php

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

form.onsubmit = function(){
var form = document.getElementById('form');  
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

formData.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
    url: "upload.php", 
    type: "post",
    data: formData
 });
}
```

Ввел некоторые исправления. Покопался в инете, почитал немного, но все еще что то не так. Поможете советом?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы уже используете jQuery, то зачаем делать смесь с чистым JS? Во-вторых, не знаю, где вы "копались в инете", но похоже, что правильные статьи по этой теме, вы обходили стороной.

```
$(function(){
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', 
            type: 'post',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function(response){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: А можете объяснить, почему мы используем e.preventDefault(); ? Т.е я знаю что она делает, но причину использования, можете коротко сказать? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: @navi1893, предотвращает выполнение стандартного действия по событию. Если простым языком, то таким способом, мы запрещаем форме отправить данные привычным ей способом.